# In which European countries can I use disposable barbecues in summer?

Tags: europe, legal, food-and-drink, parks-and-gardens

I would like to know in which European countries can I use disposable barbecues in summer?

My question focus on disposable BBQ because they have some specificities, and area easier to get for someone travelling but I would actually also be interested if the rules apply to other BBQs.

In Portugal, for instance, you are not allowed to make fires during summer (due to the risk of forest fires). But I wonder if you can use those since they light up rather fast (compared to wood). In Nordic countries, Sweden particularly, these are very common and you often see people in parks using them.
So, in the end, I would like to know in which European countries you can use them and if there are general exceptions like national parks, etc.

I am not so interested in park or city rules because those will probably be displayed on the park entrance. I would prefer the general rule/exceptions for the countries.

I am particularly interested in Portugal, Spain, France, Belgium, Germany, Netherlands, Germany, Greece and Poland, but any other information is welcome.

Additionally I would also like to know if there are any restrictions and rules besides an common sense rules you should follow whenever you use such thing and if normal BBQs are allowed instead.

[image: disposable bbq]

Comment: These things become very hot at the underside and may damage grass, that is why their use often is forbidden in German parks even where having a barbecue is generally fine.

Comment: "quicker to light up" - quicker than *what*? Than non-disposable, mobile barbecues? Than custom-built fireplaces? Than fires made in public barbecue places?

Comment: Really good question. I have used them all the time and had no clue that bbq grills were a regulated item.

Comment: To back up the claim outlined by @chirlu, here are [rules for public park areas in Cologne](http://www.stadt-koeln.de/leben-in-koeln/freizeit-natur-sport/ferien-freizeit/grillplaetze). Among others, they say: "Verwenden Sie nur einen handelsüblichen Grill, damit ein ausreichender Abstand zwischen Glut und Grasnarbe besteht. **So genannte Einweg-Grills sind nicht erlaubt.**" (emphasis by myself) = "Only use an off-the-shelf barbecue to guarantee a sufficient distance between the glow and the grass. **So-called one-way barbecues are not permitted.**"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, that's an up votable answer...

Comment: @GayotFow: Those are only exemplary rules imposed by the city Cologne. Other places in Germany may have different rules. Also, I would first like to get an answer to my question from the first comment, to get a better understanding of what the OP is actually looking for (and thus possibly suggest suitable alternatives).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, if they do not answer, then I suggest closing this one as 'unclear' and opening a new one by you.  It's a great question if it's clarified

Comment: It's not clear to me what clarification do you need?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad. As already mentioned, in Germany the rules are different from city to city and in some cities (e.g. Berlin), it even depends on the park if disposable grills are allowed or not. Some German cities do not explicitely forbid disposable grills, but impose a minimum distance between the ground and the grill (I've seen regulations with 20, 30 and 50cm), making it illegal to use a disposable grill placed directly on the ground, but ok if you place it in some kind of rack to keep it off ground.

Comment: Also note, that there are models [with legs](http://www.tagesanzeiger.ch/zuerich/stadt/Coop-macht-den-Einweggrills-Beine/story/27945800) which do less damage to the grass below it. The city of Zurich had some problem with having to fix the grass a lot in the summer after people use disposable grills and now only those with legs of at least 30cm are allowed.

Comment: Our Belgian motorcamp said NO BBQs fires etc. What harm can it do. Whoops. Ah. OK. No harm done. More or less.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo - I am not so worried in park per park rules or city per city rules, but more in country wide rules. City or park rules will probably be displayed on the park entrance.

Comment: @nsn: In Germany, the regulations are usually available online and in German only. For the larger cities, you may of course find non-official translations or summaries as well. You can not rely on the rules being posted visibly in parks or near public barbequeue areas.

Comment: @nsn: "It's not clear to me what clarification do you need?" - In my first comment, I asked a very direct question that you haven't answered yet. Anyway, while the exact words I was referring to have been removed meanwhile, "because they have some specificities" is not any more informative on what advantages you see in those disposable barbecues beside their ease in transporting. Would [ready-made public barbecue places](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Grillplatz2008.jpg) where you just need to bring some flammable material (such as wood) and your food do as an alternative?

Comment: in Poland it's specific to the city, that is if barbecuing is allowed in public parks and "recreational grounds" (basically any patch of grass). And no, this information is not displayed anywhere, just like the information if City Council put penalties on drinking alcohol and where.

Comment: We could either close this, or go for a community-wiki list answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I understand your question now. I removed that because its actually not relevant to the question. In any case these BBQ are easier to use than with real wood. They are also a bit easier to light up because they bring a soaked paper sheet (with some fuel) under the coal that it very effective. Of course you can do the same in a normal BBQ but these come prepared and they are fast to setup.

Comment: Related META question here: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/answering-portable-barbecue-question-with-a-wiki-list-answer join the discussion

Answer (score 1):

In Hungary you may build a fire/have a barbecue while respecting the general rules of campfires (stay far from the forest area, clean the land of dry stuff before lighting a fire, put it out when you leave etc.). During the year the state officialities may issue "fire restriction periods" which are made public on websites and radio (but unfortunately only in Hungarian, yet you can follow them permanently [here](https://www.nebih.gov.hu/szakteruletek/szakteruletek/erdeszeti_igazgatosag/erdeszet_szakteruletek/erdo_tuzvedelem/tuzgyujt_til_terkep) or [here](http://www.katasztrofavedelem.hu/index2.php?pageid=monitor_tuzgyujtasi_tilalom), together with general information about fires and regulations). This might occur when the weather is very hot or there was no rain for some time; in these periods of time (may last weeks) lighting a fire is strictly prohibited and severely punished with high fees.

In Romania the forestry may issue general rules (there must be at least 30 m distance from the closest forest, fire must be put out etc.) or special rules for certain areas (national parks or endangered areas - here usually fires are strictly prohibited and there are signs which tell you this when entering the area). Picnic and barbecue should be made in specially prepared places. Yet no rules are kept - people make fires wherever they like, and forestry doesn't really care about fining them for it. Details and fees can be found [here](http://lege5.ro/en/Gratuit/geztmmjrhe/legea-nr-171-2010-privind-stabilirea-si-sanctionarea-contraventiilor-silvice) (only in Romanian, unfortunately).